# Azure AD B2C: Create a sign up user flow with success page at end of flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Can I use Azure AD B2C to create a sign up user flow that redirects the user to a page that displays something like "User account successfully created" page after the new user account has been created?

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT, could you please help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is via a [paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#paragraph) tag.

There's an [example](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f) here.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I follow correctly. What I want is for a page at the end of a successful registration, instead of an empty page like it currently is.

Comment: If you are using custom policies, you can add the page you require by using that tag.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll check again and see if the built-in user flow provides something like that by default. (Do you know if it does?)

Comment: I'm not aware of one.